# Python Scrapy - multiple variables in start_url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to make make my start_url a bit more dynamic than it currently is but my adjusted code doesn't seem to work.

In order to make it more dynamic, I've added 2 more variables (month and day), and changed over to using the `start_requests` method instead of `start_urls`, however, the scraper now returns zero items:

```
import scrapy

class SuhbaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "suhbaDate"
# old working line of code 
#    start_urls = ["http://saltanat.org/videos.php?date={yyyy}-06-15".format(yyyy=yyyy) for yyyy in range(2013,2020)]

# new block of code (replaced start_urls with start_requests), not working
    def start_requests(self):
        for yyyy in range(2013,2020):
            for mm in range(12,12):
                for dd in range(14,15):
                    url = "http://saltanat.org/videos.php?date={yyyy}-{mm}-{dd}".format(yyyy=yyyy,mm=mm,dd=dd) 
                    yield Request(url, meta={'start_url':url}, callback=self.parse)
                    print(yyyy,mm,dd,url)

    def parse(self, response):
        for video in response.xpath("//tr[@class='video-doclet-row']"):
            item = dict()
            item["video"] = video.xpath(".//span[@class='download make-cursor']/a/@href").extract_first()

            videoid = video.xpath(".//span[@class='media-info make-cursor']/@onclick").extract_first()
            url = "http://saltanat.org/ajax_transcription.php?vid=" + videoid[21:-2]
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_transcript)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse_transcript(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item["transcript"] = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'english')]/@href").extract_first()
        yield item
```

Any assistance will be appreciated

Comment: Have you printed out each of `yyyy`, `mm`, `dd` and `url` in each iteration to make sure they're correct?

Comment: @MattDMo it seems to only print the first loop (years) and not continue to the other loops

Comment: Well, for one thing, `for mm in range(12,12):` is not going to give you anything.

Comment: yup, that's a typo from my end. When looking at the Traceback the actual problem turned out to be with the ```Requests``` keyword. The solution was to include this line at the top ```from scrapy.http.request import Request```. Thanks for your help though, using the print function definitely got me thinking in the right direction

Comment: @MattDMo thanks for the suggestion to use print and analyse the output, it definitely got me going on the right direction

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find the issues. In the future, [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) provides some pretty timeless advice, for any language.

Comment: @MattDMo thanks for the article, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were a couple of problems with the above code code

1. Looking at the Traceback output it was found that the actual problem was this:
   `NameError: global name 'Request' is not defined` which seems to be a bug
2. The url in question needed a leading zero for the `mm` and `dd` variables

**The solution**

1. Included this line at the top of the script `from scrapy.http.request import Request`
2. Rewrote the `start_requests` loop with itertools and zfill:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for yyyy,mm,dd in itertools.product(range(2013,2020),range(6,7),range(14,22)):
        mm = str(mm).zfill(2)
        dd = str(dd).zfill(2)
        url = "http://saltanat.org/videos.php?date={0}-{1}-{2}".format(yyyy,mm,dd) 
        yield Request(url, meta={'start_url':url}, callback=self.parse)
```

**ignore the actual dates, those are for testing*